# How to resize google infoWindow

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have a problem using infoWindow on Google Maps to show some information. I want to make this white div smaller so that it can match in size the grey box inside it. And I want to make this "white" arrow which is going from the marker to the white div to be smaller too.

Here is the picture:
[image]

My code:

```
var contentString = '<form >'+
  '<h2><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Data:</b></h2>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<div style=width:220px;display:inline-block;>'+
  '<p>&nbsp;' +'</p>' + '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' + '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' +
  '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' + '</div>'+
  '<div style=width:220px;display:inline-block;>'+
  '<p>&nbsp;' +'</p>' + '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' + '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' +
  '<p>&nbsp;' + '</p>' + '</div>'+ '</div>'+ '</form>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});
/* info window */
infowindow.open(map,tracked);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the size of your infoWindow a couple of ways. One would be to set the `width`  and `height` of your `<form>` tag in the `contentString`, which is essentially the styling of the white infoWindow. So, `<form style="width:240px; height:240px">`.

The other option is to set the `maxWidth` option for your infoWindow - there is no option for `height`, that adjusts according to your content I believe. Refer to the [Google Maps API Reference for infoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions). You'll have to set it up like so:

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 240
    });
```

However, I don't think there is anyway with the current API that you can change the size of the "white" arrow. You could look into using the [infoBubble Library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) - it is one of many open source libraries that you can use with Google Maps (here's a link to the others: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). Pretty much, you'll declare the infoBubble the same as you would the infoWindow - but you have more options for styling - specifically for your case you can change the `arrowSize`:

```
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        content: contentString,
        minWidth: 240, //width of your infoWindow/infoBubble
        arrowSize: 3 //set your desired size            
    });
```

Comment: Just what I needed :) I used infoBubble and it is a really nice library. thank you

Comment: Do you maybe know how can I check if infobubble is opened? as I need to change some values inside of it. Is there any refresh or something

Comment: good to know it does, have a look from Line 948 in http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js?r=206 i believe you can do `infoBubble.isOpen()`

Comment: yes you were right , but problem is than everytime I update position I am having a infowindow poping. I need to find the way to make it stable

Comment: not quite sure i understand what you mean..can u provide a link or put something together on jsfiddle so i can recreate your issue and try to find a solution?

Comment: For example: you have a marker that is moving and it has inside the valus of the certain variables so I can show them to user. When marker is moving it is taking a lot of time and resources to draw a new marker and infoWindow. So I need something to refresh the existing marker. I have tried with the isOpen() but hen I need to redraw it. Is there any refresh method?

Comment: sorry, i'm still not entirely sure how to create the problem you're running into to help you out